# 0 value flow with atleast 1 edge with flow greater than 0, min subset of bottleneck edges

Tags: graph-theory

I was given the following flow network problems to solve

1. write an efficient algorithm that takes in a flow network G
   and determines whether there exists a valid 0-value s-t flow
   with atleast 1 edge in the network with flow greater than 0
2. write an algorithm that takes in a flow network G and a max-flow function f
   and returns the minimum set of bottleneck edges i.e edges that when we increase their capacity
   it increases the max flow value

for the first question, i initially thought of finding circulations of flow inside the graph for which flow never leaves them and so there would be such edges with flow, and we could find a valid 0 value s-t flow

for the second one, the only thing i came up with was examining the edges in the min-cut, generating all subsets of edges and taking the minimum number of edges subset..

both are insufficient, the first is only a lead which i couldn't expand on
and the second is very computation expsensive and so i wonder if i can do it better

also, if my intuition is incorrect i would appreciate pointing that out

i will say that none of the existing questions and answers here were helpful for these problems, and so i made this post.

Comment: "a valid 0-value s-t flow with flow greater than 0"  What does this mean?  Please post a small example..

Comment: "a max-flow function f"  what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

The standard algorithm for finding the flow through a network goes like this:

- Find a path from a source to a destination, using depth first search
- Find minimum capacity of any link on the path
- Reduce capacity of all links on path by minimum capacity
- Remove any edges that now has zero capacity
- Repeat above steps until no more paths can be found.

"the minimum set of bottleneck edges"

The edges that have zero surplus capacity are the bottlenecks.